# How do we set row template for a single row while using Kendo Grid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, grid, kendo-ui

How do we set row template for a single row while using Kendo Grid? I need to get the total of the values in the columns of the rest of the rows in the final row. Like a Summary to the grid in the last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to reflect edited question**

You can create the needed values by using aggregates in your datasource and then you can display the values in a footer by using the footerTemplate option for the columns in the Grid

I've prepared an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rTrzc/

Comment: I want it like a footer row, where you'll find the sum of values in the columns of all the above rows. I meant in the final row, not column. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks Jesper, that was indeed the way to do it! :)